# How to know the maximum capacity of memory/RAM of a server?

Tags: memory, dell-poweredge

I have a [Dell PowerEdge T410](http://configure.us.dell.com/dellstore/config.aspx?oc=bedw52h&model_id=poweredge-t410&c=us&l=en&s=bsd&cs=04&) and have installed 16Gb RAM for it.

I don't know if I can extend it to 32Gb, 64Gb, ... RAM on this server corresponding to my customized configuration

**So my question is, how to know exactly the maximum capacity of memory/RAM of a server?**

I need this information so as to verify the number by myself.

*ps.*

My server is not exactly the same as the description on Dell website - I indeed modify the configuration to meet my budget. Currently this is my purchased [server configuration](https://www.dropbox.com/s/g9ufes8im1e6jsh/03%20NN%20tower%20server.pdf)

Comment: We're still not your hardware purchasing consultants, but I see nothing in the "customised configuration" you've given that would limit the system to anything less than the full compliment of RAM available.

Comment: Have you tried RTFFM?  Or forget the manual, you can find that specification in the tech specs or even the sales sheets for the platform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The maximum RAM is determined by your CPU and your mainboard. You have to look up the maximum memory capacity of both and the lowest of the numbers is your maximum.

### Edit

You can choose up to 24GB of RAM if you take the option for a second processor.

Comment: I'm newbie to server/hardware. Please continue to help me on how to read the memory capacity of CPU & mainboard? Thank you

Comment: The mainbard can take up to 128GB so it is not the Problem now just google for the specifications of the CPU you want to choose. Intel CPUs a well documented so you will find the maximum RAM very easy.

Comment: The CPU doesn't have much of anything to do with the amount of memory that can be supported, the motherboard chipset (and available DIMM slots) is the determining factor.

Comment: CPUs do have a memory limit though it is very high for some CPUs. See the memory section at: http://ark.intel.com/products/52582/Intel-Xeon-Processor-E5607-%288M-Cache-2_26-GHz-4_80-GTs-Intel-QPI%29

Comment: Are there any E56xx CPUs that have a different memory limit, though?

Comment: I don't know all the specs of all CPUs. I don't buy Hardware (just my own). I only knew that CPUs have an upper limit for RAM.

Answer (score 7):

Read [the specs for the server](http://www.dell.com/us/business/p/poweredge-t410/pd#TechSpec).  Says right there, "Up to 128GB"

Comment: Thank you. I see `Up to 128GB` - but what exactly then? @ChristopherPerrin give me the best way to get this by looking at the CPU and mainboard.

Comment: "What then" *what*?  You've determined the maximum amount of memory your chassis can support.  Problem solved.  Got another question?  Ask a new question.

Comment: "What then" is the maximum RAM amount corresponding to the number of CPUs

Comment: Your question does not contain the string "CPU" nor "central", "processing", "processor", or "unit".  We don't read minds.

Comment: Yeah you are right. I missed to bring in the text `maximum RAM of the server after my customized configuration`

Answer (score 5):

Seriously? Another question that can be self-answered by applying a little effort and looking on the vendor's web site for the relevant information?

http://www.dell.com/us/business/p/poweredge-t410/pd

Comment: Think of it as a "rep gift".

Comment: I buy the server and customized it due to my budget my friend. So the url you give will answer `Up to 128GB` - but what exactly then? @ChristopherPerrin give me the best way to get this by looking at the CPU and mainboard.